# Confusion matrix, metrics, & joint vs. conditional probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability, terminology, precision-recall, confusion-matrix

In the binary classification/prediction problem we have unknown labels $y\in\{0,1\}$, which we try to predict using an estimator $\hat{y}$. Commonly the performance of an estimator is summarized using a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix), and many related [performance metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers).

I have not done much work in this area, and reading about things like [precision-recall](/questions/tagged/precision-recall), I can definitely sympathize with things like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122225/what-is-the-best-way-to-remember-the-difference-between-sensitivity-specificity)!

To the extent I have thought about these issues, I find it much clearer to the think about things in terms of [joint/marginal/conditional probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236277/what-does-it-mean-to-factor-a-joint-distribution). But then things like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144861/why-the-sum-of-true-positive-and-false-positive-does-not-have-to-be-equal-to-one) make me less certain of my understanding.

So I am looking for an explanation of the relationships between:

1. Standard confusion-matrix related terminology (see big Table at Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers))
2. The various probability distributions of $y$ and $\hat{y}$ (i.e. [joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) vs. [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) vs. [marginal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution))

Is there something like a "dictionary" to translate between the two descriptions?

---

**Process Note:** I have a notion of the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) I am looking for, which I *think* could be useful to others as well. However I am not fully certain, and could use [feedback](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/soliciting-feedback-vs-asking-a-question) in any case. So I will be drafting an "answer" below, but hope others more knowledgeable may respond as well. (Also, I do not *believe* this is a duplicate, but if I missed an existing Q & A please let me know.)

Comment: This is a nice question (+1). Have you head about [scoring rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule) and in particular *strict proper scoring rules*? I think they will be enlightening for you when it comes into assessing the probability distributions $\hat{y}$.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks! I have heard about these (from this site, in fact). Skimmed a couple Tetlock papers, been meaning to read *Superforecasters* :)

Comment: Ah... the famous *books-I-have-been-meaning-to-read* list :) If I have read a half of the ones on my list I would probably be an ASA fellow by now. Slightly more seriously: Chambers (2007) "*Proper scoring rules for general decision models*" and Merkle & Steyvers (2013) "*Choosing a strictly proper scoring rule*" are interesting reads. (read them last week :D...)

Answer (score 6):

For predicted labels $\hat{y}$ and true labels $y\in\{0,1\}$, the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) is given by

\begin{array}{c|c:c|c}
 & y=0 & y=1 & \\
\hline
\hat{y}=0 & \mathrm{TN} & \mathrm{FN} & \hat{\mathrm{N}} \\
\hdashline
\hat{y}=1 & \mathrm{FP} & \mathrm{TP} & \hat{\mathrm{P}} \\
\hline
& \mathrm{N} & \mathrm{P} & (n_{\mathrm{obs}})
\end{array}

where the entries are [counts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_data), $\mathrm{N}$ = "Negative", $\mathrm{P}$ = "Positive", $\mathrm{T}$ = "True", and $\mathrm{F}$ = "False".

The confusion matrix proper is contained within the solid-outlined box, to which I have added the column sums ($\mathrm{N}$,$\mathrm{P}$), column sums ($\hat{\mathrm{N}}$,$\hat{\mathrm{P}}$), and total sum ($n_{\mathrm{obs}}$ = number of paired observations).

The confusion matrix is essentially an [empirical estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_probability) of the [joint distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) between $\hat{y}$ and $y$, i.e. when the entries are normalized by $n_{\mathrm{obs}}$ we get

\begin{array}{c|c:c|c}
 & y=0 & y=1 & \\
\hline
\hat{y}=0 & p[\sim\!\hat{y},\sim\!y] & p[\sim\!\hat{y},\phantom{\sim\!}y] & p[\sim\!\hat{y}] \\
\hdashline
\hat{y}=1 & p[\phantom{\sim}\,\hat{y},\sim\!y] & p[\phantom{\sim}\,\hat{y},\phantom{\sim\!}y] & p[\phantom{\sim}\,\hat{y}] \\
\hline
& p[\phantom{\sim\hat{y}}\sim\!y] & p[\phantom{\sim\hat{y},,}\,y] & (1)
\end{array}
where I have switched to a [Boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)-style notation with $\sim$ = "not".

In the *margins* of the table (outside the box), the normalized row and column sums are now the [marginal probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution).

Within this framework, many of the standard [confusion matrix based metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers) correspond directly to the various [conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) of the above joint distribution.

---

If we condition on $\boldsymbol{y}$ the table becomes
\begin{array}{|c:c|}
\hline
p[\sim\!\hat{y}\mid\sim\!y] & p[\sim\!\hat{y}\mid\phantom{\sim\!}y] \\
\hdashline
p[\phantom{\sim}\,\hat{y}\mid\sim\!y] & p[\phantom{\sim}\,\hat{y}\mid\phantom{\sim\!}y] \\
\hline
\end{array}

where the entries correspond to the metrics
\begin{array}{|c:c|}
\hline
\text{specificity}
&
\text{miss rate} \\
\hdashline
\text{fall-out}
&
\text{sensitivity (recall)}
\\
\hline
\end{array}
 (Note that these metrics can also be referred to by appending "rate" to the corresponding name from the confusion matrix.)

---

Alternatively, if we condition on $\boldsymbol{\hat{y}}$ the table becomes
\begin{array}{|c:c|}
\hline
p[\sim\!y\mid\sim\!\hat{y}] & p[\phantom{\sim\!}y\mid\sim\!\hat{y}] \\
\hdashline
p[\sim\!y\mid\phantom{\sim}\hat{y}] & p[\phantom{\sim\!}y\mid\phantom{\sim}\hat{y}] \\
\hline
\end{array}

where the entries correspond to the metrics
\begin{array}{|c:c|}
\hline
\text{negative predictive value}
&
\text{false omission rate}^* \\
\hdashline
\text{false discovery rate}
&
\text{positive predictive value (precision)}
\\
\hline
\end{array}
(*This one was not in Wikipedia except in their "big table". I was curious why it was the *only one* of the conditional probabilities not given a special name.)

Comment: By asking a question here you should want to here comments or proposed answers of others.  You didn't wait very long for that and so you got nothing.  Did you do this just to try to teach us something?

Comment: Sorry I reread your question completely and see you are open for answers using your answer as a talking point.